# Is it possible to Cache the result set of a select query in the database?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005

I am trying to optimize the search query which is the most used in our system. So far I have added some missing indexes and that has helped slightly. But I want to further reduce the load on the db server. One option that I will use is caching the result set as a LIST in the asp.net Cache so that I don't have to hit the db often.

However, I was wondering if there is a way to Cache some portions of the select query at the db as well. e.g. for the search results we consider only users who have been active in the last 180 days and who have share-info set as true. So this is like a super set which the db processes everytime and then applies other conditions such as category specified, city etc. which are passed. Is it possible to somehow Cache the Super Set so that I can run queries against the super set rather than run the query against the whole table? Will creating a View help in this? I am a bit hesitant to create a view as I read managing views can be an overhead and takes away some flexibility to modfy the tables.

I am using Sql-Server 2005 so cannot create a filtered index on the table, which I think would have been helpful.

Comment: Can you post the search query that is slow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Neville K. SQL Server is pretty smart at caching data in memory. You might see limited / no performance gains for your effort.

You could consider indexed views (Enterprise Edition only) http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917715.aspx for your sub-query.

Comment: I am trying out an Indexed View. However, my server is not Enterprise Edition. I read somewhere earlier today that if it is not enterprise edition, one can still use indexed view but need to explicitly state using some keyword. Can't seem to find what the keyword was.

Comment: Ok, to force the query to use the view, the keyword is NOEXPAND which is mentioned in the article you shared. Unfortunately it doesnt lead to any performance improvements.

Comment: You are right that there would be limited or no perf gains. I am now looking at caching the objects in the app tier and try not hit the db as often.

Answer (score 0):

It is, of course, possible to do this - but I'm not sure if it will help.

You can create a scheduled job - once a night, perhaps - which populates a table called "active_users_with_share_info" by truncating it, and then repopulating it based on a select query filtering out users active in the last 180 days with "share_info = true".

Then you can join your search query to this table.

However, I doubt this would do much good - SQL Server is pretty smart at caching. Unless you're dealing with huge volumes of data (100 of millions of records), or very limited hardware, I doubt you'd get any measurable performance improvements - but by all means try it!

Of course, the price for this would be more moving parts in your application, more interesting failure modes (what happens if the overnight batch fails silently?), and more training for any new developers you bring into the team.